# Does the repaint() get called automatically sometimes?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, concurrentmodification

I'm making a game. Each object in the game is registered in a registry. I have an update and render method being called by a game loop. The render method calls `repaint()` on my `JPanel` and I have overridden `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for graphics. When it renders and updates, it goes through each object and updates it and renders it from the registry. Sometimes I get a concurrent modification error, and i believe it is because something is calling the `paintComponent()` other than from my game loop. If a `JPanel` or even `JFrame` calls repaint on its own, is there any way to disable it?

Comment: *"paintComponent() other than from my game loop"* - First, you should never be calling in paint method yourself (even printing should be done via the print methods). Second, if you call repaint, a paint event will be scheduled by the repaint manager and (eventually) processed by the Event Dispatching Thread. When and how this is done comes down to how the repaint manager schedules these events. This means that all painting is done within the context of the EDT (unless you are doing something you shouldn't be). This means  painting is never done fro within the context of your game loop

Comment: Concurrent modifications sound suspiciously like you are modifying data in a thread other than the EDT, and also accessing the same data when drawing. This is not wrong by itself, but you *need* to provide the appropriate guards in that situation. As others have pointed out, the scheduling of the painting is unpredictable, and may overlap your modifications. This can happen even without additional paint requests resulting from system events.

Comment: however updates are reflected immediately unlike you painting yourself or everything inside your component whenever you doing it in the main thread or in a daemon thread it depends on the GUI architecture.

Comment: I noticed the `ConcurrentModification`. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21541991/2587435)

Answer (score 5):

No, `repaint()` doesn't get called automatically, but `paint(Graphics g)` does at times, and you have no control over this. Also, your `repaint()` calls may be ignored if they get "stacked". For more on this, please check out this article: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Hopefully you have no program logic inside of your paintComponent method. If you do, get it out of there.

Answer (score 3):

> "paintComponent() other than from my game loop"

First, you should never be calling any paint method yourself (even printing should be done via the print methods).

Second, if you call repaint, a paint event will be scheduled by the repaint manager and (eventually) processed by the Event Dispatching Thread. When and how this is done comes down to how the repaint manager schedules these events. This means that all painting is done within the context of the EDT (unless you are doing something you shouldn't be). This means painting is never done from within the context of your game loop

This means, if your changing the state of the game that the paint routines rely on, you will have concurrent issues.

You could synchronize the shared data structures so that they can't be accessed while some other thread is accessing the data.

You could render the state of the to a backing buffer within the game thread, then assign it to a active buffer. Thus is kind of like a double buffering approach