# animated background java game

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, 2d-games

I was programming a game similar to asteroid, but I do not understand how to spawn the asteroids in the background.

[image: http://gyazo.com/aebb41b4ef4074823fc46e8e124fc570]

now i spawn an asteroid in the main class but i want create a class for the asteroid ho i do it?

MAIN CLASS

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(flag_img)
    {
        background(g2d);  
        logo(g2d);          
        menu(g2d);          
        spaceship(g2d);   
        crediti(g2d);    
    }
}
```

background function(now)

```
private void background(Graphics2D g2d) 
{

    asteroidi_g_x+=r.nextInt(4);
    asteroidi_g_y+=r.nextInt(1);
    g2d.drawImage(asteroidi_g[0], asteroidi_g_x,asteroidi_g_y,this);
}
```

background function(what i want)

```
private void background(Graphics2D g2d) 
{
    asteroid asteroid = new asteroid[10];
}
```

and class asteroid

```
public class asteroid extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
   private BufferedImage images_asteroid;
   private boolean flag_img;

   private JPanel jp;

   private int x,y;

   public asteroide_grande(JPanel jp)
   {
    flag_img = true;
    x = (jp.getWidth()/2);
    y = (jp.getHeight()/2);
    this.jp = jp;

        try {
            images_asterod = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("images/asteroid/a1.png"));
        } catch(IOException e){flag = false;}
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
   if(flag_img)
  {
        g.drawImage(images_asteroid, 100, 100,this);
  }
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    x=x-1;
    y=y+1;
    repaint();
}
```

method paintcomponent in class doesn't work

Comment: You want to just move that _one_ asteroid in the image? That's it?

Comment: i want spawn an array of asteroid (10), when i instantiate an asteroid the class costructor generate a random coordinate and the asteroid move in the jpanel

Comment: See my edit below with a full example.

Comment: Instead of using an array, I just used a `List`, when I loop through it in the Timer, if the asteroid is off the screen, I remove it from the list. I also add a new asteroid every second as a random x location

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't have your `Asteroid` class extends `JPanel`. Instead have it as a class that model's asteroid data and has data manipulation methods. You'll also want to have a `draw` method that take a `Graphic` context. Something like

   ```
   public class Asteroid {
       Image asteroidImage;
       JPanel panel;
       int x, y;

       public Asteroid(JPanel panel, Image image, int x, int y) {
           this.panel = panel;
           this.asteroidImage = image;
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
       }

       public void drawAsteroid(Graphics g) {
           g.drawImage(asteroidImage, x, y, panel);
       }

       public void move() {
           x += 5;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now you have a model of an asteroid, you can create a `List` of `Asteriod` objects and iterate through them and use it's `drawAsteroid` method to paint them. Something like

   ```
   public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
       List<Asteroid> asteroids;
       Image asteroidImage;

       public GamePanel(){
           asteroidImage = ...
           asteroids = new ArrayList<>();
           asteroids.add(new Asteroid(GamePanel.this, asteroidImage, 100, 100));
           // add more asteriods
       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           for (Asteriod asteroid: asteriods) {
               asteriod.drawAsteroid(g);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. To animate them, you'll want to use a `javax.swing.Timer`. See more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). You'll want to manipulate the `Asteriod` data in the `Timer`. With the code provided above, you can just call it's `move` method, then call `repaint()`. Something like

   ```
   public GamePanel(){
       ...
       Timer timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               Iterator it = asteroids.iterator();
               while (it.hasNaext()) {
                   Asteroid asteriod = (Asteroid)it.next();
                   asteroid.move();
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```

---

You can see a bunch more complete example of animating multiple objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593458/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534549/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801845/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22123304/2587435)

---

Here's a full example. You'll see I included a `Rectangle2D` object in the `Astreroid` class. That's just if you want to check for collision detection. You should move the `Rectangle2D` `x` and/or `y` with every `Asreroid` movement of `x` and `y`. Then you can check if `asteroid.rectangle.intersects(someOtherObject)`

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AsteroidBackground extends JPanel {

    private static final int D_W = 400;
    private static final int D_H = 600;
    BufferedImage asteroidImage;
    BufferedImage background;
    List<Asteroid> asteroids;
    Random random = new Random();
    int countToAddAsteroid = 0;
    int y;

    public AsteroidBackground() {
        try {
            asteroidImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/small-asteroid.png"));
            background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/space.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AsteroidBackground.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        asteroids = new ArrayList<>();
        y = 0 - asteroidImage.getHeight();

        Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (countToAddAsteroid >= 25) {
                    int randX = random.nextInt(D_W);
                    asteroids.add(new Asteroid(AsteroidBackground.this, asteroidImage, randX, y));
                    countToAddAsteroid = 0;
                }
                countToAddAsteroid++;
                Iterator it = asteroids.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Asteroid asteroid = (Asteroid)it.next();
                    if (asteroid.y >= D_H) {
                        it.remove();
                    } else {
                         asteroid.move();
                    } 
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        for (Asteroid asteroid : asteroids) {
            asteroid.drawAsteroid(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

    public class Asteroid {
        Rectangle2D rectangle;
        Image asteroidImage;
        JPanel panel;
        int x, y;

        public Asteroid(JPanel panel, Image image, int x, int y) {
            this.panel = panel;
            this.asteroidImage = image;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                    x, y, image.getWidth(panel), image.getHeight(panel));
        }

        public void drawAsteroid(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(asteroidImage, x, y, panel);
        }

        public void move() {
            y += 5;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new AsteroidBackground());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```